# Mejor forma para pasar varias variables

Tags: javascript, variables

Muy buenas, tengo un formulario en el que  al darle a aceptar, tengo que pasarle el contenido de 5 campos a una funcion, mi duda es: Hay alguna forma un poco mas eficiente para pasar 5 variables a una funcion? Quizas Json ? Muchas gracias

Comment: no has formulado una buena pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que leas el [tour] para poder hacer una pregunta de calidad y no basada en opiniones como es ahora.

Comment: Hola Lorenzo. Dices que si hay *una manera más eficiente*... pero no muestras la manera actual en la que lo realizas. Mejora la pregunta para que no haya rastro de subjetividad. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que estás planteando la pregunta desde un enfoque equivocado. Más que cuestión de eficiencia es cuestión de legibilidad o comodidad (especialmente si hay parámetros opcionales).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes muchas variables es más cómodo que crees un objeto y lo pases como parámetro directamente.

Te dejo un ejemplo simple:

```js
var obj = {
            valor1 : 1,
            valor2 : 2,
            valor3 : 3,
            valor4 : 4,
            valor5 : 5
           }
            
function Ejemplo(objeto) {
  console.log(objeto.valor2);
}

Ejemplo(obj);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a los tres, todos me habéis aportado algo, he estado buscando en el diccionario y ya se que lo significa subjetividad. Respecto al compañero Aitor, decirle que su respuesta era justo  lo que quería y que me alegro mucho de que haya logrado entender una pregunta tan mal formulada. Gracias